# LinQ query doesn't order

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a strange issue. The code below, once executed, does not use any form of ORDER BY in the sql statement, and so it does not return the intented records.

```
var last5CommesseRisorsaPjId = db.Attivita
                    .Where(a => a.IdRisorsa == loggedUser.Id)
                    .OrderByDescending(a => a.Data)      //this looks ignored
                    .Select(a => a.FasiCommessa.Commesse.AxProjId)
                    .Distinct()
                    .Take(5)
                    .ToList();
```

**SQL:** (using db.Database.Log):

```
SELECT 
[Limit1].[AxProjId] AS [AxProjId]
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT TOP (5) 
    [Extent3].[AxProjId] AS [AxProjId]
    FROM   [dbo].[Attivita] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[FasiCommessa] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[IdFaseCommessa] = [Extent2].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Commesse] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[IdCommessa] = [Extent3].[Id]
    WHERE [Extent1].[IdRisorsa] = 'ecaffee0-5aeb-45cf-8d40-218ff63a2108'
)  AS [Limit1]
```

I would expect an `ORDER BY [Extent1].[Data] DESC` after the `WHERE` clause.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved rewriting the query as below:

```
var last5CommesseRisorsaPjId = db.Attivita
                   .Where(a => a.IdRisorsa == loggedUser.Id)
                   .GroupBy(a => a.FasiCommessa.Commesse.AxProjId)
                   .Select(g => new { AxProjId = g.Key, MaxData = g.Max(a => a.Data) })
                   .OrderByDescending(c => c.MaxData)
                   .Select(c => c.AxProjId)
                   .Take(5)
                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

The distinct is probably messing up the order by try calling the orderBy after the distinct()

```
 var last5CommesseRisorsaPjId = db.Attivita
                    .Where(a => a.IdRisorsa == loggedUser.Id)
                    .Distinct()
                    .OrderByDescending(a => a.Data)      //this looks ignored
                    .Select(a => a.FasiCommessa.Commesse.AxProjId)
                    .Take(5)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: But the Distinct just after the where would apply on the whole record, I need the Distinct on a => a.FasiCommessa.Commesse.AxProjId

Comment: you can use the select query before the distinct

Comment: but if I use the select before the distinct, it will be before the OrderBy too, so I won't be able to order by something I didn't include in the Select clause

Answer (score 1):

Call Distinict First and then OrderBy

Comment: As written in the above answer's comments, the distinct would not work as intended if I move the distinct before the orderby (it will be before the select too)